# Why the if statement is ignoring the command line argument?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a simple program that takes one argument. I use as main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argv[1] == "string") {
        cout<<"STRING AS ARG!!"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it with `program.exe string` nothing happens. What is wrong with the piece of code?

Comment: If you turned on warnings, you'd know why that's happening https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a7Pqf1

Comment: I use msvc++ as compiler not gcc

Comment: MSVC has produces the same warning https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b8dYax

Comment: Idk. I don't get any error message... https://imgur.com/a/8TeF5ws Only some warnings about irrelevant things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that both operands are C strings and the comparison does a raw pointer comparison. You need to make at least one operand a `std::string` or a `std::string_view`.

`std::string_view` is the best option because it avoids the overhead of the `std::string`, but you need C++17:

```
#include <string_view>
using namespace std::literals;

if (argv[1] == "string"sv)
```

The `std::string` versions. If you have C++14 you can use the literal:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

if (argv[1] == "string"s)
```

Or if you are pre C++14:

```
#include <string>

if (argv[1] == std::string("string"))
```

Comment: @Kon please don't edit the code if you don't understand it properly

Comment: @Kon your edit turned correct code into incorrect code.

Answer (score 3):

`argv[1]` is a pointer (`char *`). You can not compare it to "string" using `==`, it'll always return false. You should use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "string") == 0)
```

Comment: there is no `string` in the example and comparing a `string` to a `char *` would in fact work and give the correct result.

Comment: You can't use == to compare a string literal to a `char *`. You must use `strcmp()`. The example clearly has "string" in the if statement. We're talking about a string literal ("string") and not the C++ string type.